# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=-569622516

Tags: android

I encountered a very difficult problem. My app from the splash page into the home page during the following anomalies, resulting in the application of flashback, exception information does not contain any of my app's call stack information, so I do not know exactly what the implementation of the code caused the exception.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=-665300980
    android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getSpanFlags(SpannableStringBuilder.java:838)
    android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.removeComposingSpans(BaseInputConnection.java:94)
    android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.finishComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:450)
    com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:431)
    com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:93)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6295)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:790)
```

Comment: Please post some code as well. Just the stacktrace doesn't make any sense

Comment: Show your line of code where it's crashing

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: did you find why cause this crash now?

Answer (score 1):

According to your error i figure that array is causing problem check out your code whether you are calling out of index array at the runtime.
Checkout your mainactivity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are used **array.indexOf(object)** for find the index of value at your string. That's why you getting this issue.

**indexOf(value)** will return unexpected index if value not in string.

**indexOf(value)** will return original index if value is in string.

For EX:

```
  String s="serach text";
  int x= s.indexOf("h");//return index as 5
  int y= s.indexOf("y");//return index as unexpected index
  if(y>=0){
   //your true case
  }else{
    //your false case
  }
```

so check your index is valid or not before use.

Comment: The exception is not my code, but the system code. My splashActivity and MainActivity did not call the api associated with spannableStringBuilder at all

Comment: @N Dh  will you post your code ? it's will helpful to find the issue